# how to add values to certain index in column in pandas dataframe (python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe (results) like this:

| index | results |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | -1 |
| 2 | 1 |

I have another dataframe (signals) like this:

| index | signals |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 200 |
| 1 | 300 |
| 2 | 250 |
| 3 | 450 |
| 4 | 345 |
| 5 | 534 |

I want to add a column in signals such that the value from results will be copied twice in that column like

| index | signals | results |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 200 | 1 |
| 1 | 300 | 1 |
| 2 | 250 | -1 |
| 3 | 450 | -1 |
| 4 | 345 | 1 |
| 5 | 534 | 1 |

Note: The 1 from index 0 from results is copied twice in index 0 and 1 of signals and so on.
How can i go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep it simple, just use the Series' [`repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.repeat.html) method:

```
n = len(signals) // len(results)
signals['results'] = result['results'].repeat(n).to_numpy()
```

output:

```
   index   signals  results
0       0      200        1
1       1      300        1
2       2      250       -1
3       3      450       -1
4       4      345        1
5       5      534        1
```

Comment: Yes, it's better than use Index.repeat... I forgot the Series.repeat. +1

Comment: The global logic is the same. Already +1'd all ;)

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you just want to repeat `results` twice and assign it to a column in `signals`, right? In that case, you can use, `np.repeat`:

```
import numpy as np
signals['results'] = np.repeat(results['results'].to_numpy(), 2)
```

Output:

```
   index  signals  results
0      0      200        1
1      1      300        1
2      2      250       -1
3      3      450       -1
4      4      345        1
5      5      534        1
```

Answer (score 2):

*The @mozway's answer is more relevant than mine because he uses `Series.repeat` instead `Index.repeat`. The @Manlai's answer is interesting too.*

Use `Index.repeat`:

```
n = len(signals) // len(results)  # twice
signals['results'] = results.reindex(results.index.repeat(n)).to_numpy()
print(signals)

# Output
   signals  results
0      200        1
1      300        1
2      250       -1
3      450       -1
4      345        1
5      534        1
```